# Show card section according to active IonSegmentButton

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

**.tsx**

```
import { IonCard, IonCardHeader, IonContent, IonPage, IonSegment, IonSegmentButton } from '@ionic/react';
import './example.css';

const Example: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent fullscreen class="ion-padding">
        <div>
          <IonSegment value="1" color="primary" mode="md">    
            <IonSegmentButton value="1">
                Segment 1
            </IonSegmentButton>
            <IonSegmentButton value="2">
                Segment 2
            </IonSegmentButton>
            <IonSegmentButton value="3">
                Segment 3
            </IonSegmentButton>
          </IonSegment>

          <div>   
            {/* Segment 1 Content */}
            <IonCard class="ion-no-margin ion-padding-bottom">
              <IonCardHeader>
                  1
              </IonCardHeader>
            </IonCard>

            {/* Segment 2 Content */}
            <IonCard class="ion-no-margin ion-padding-bottom">
              <IonCardHeader>
                  2
              </IonCardHeader>
            </IonCard>

            {/* Segment 3 Content */}
            <IonCard class="ion-no-margin ion-padding-bottom">
              <IonCardHeader>
                  3
              </IonCardHeader>
            </IonCard>
          </div>

        </div>
      </IonContent>
        
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

How to show the card section according to the active IonSegmentButton?
As in angular, we use `*ngSwitchCase="'1'"` how to do in React?

`useState` can be used? Solution Please!

Ref.: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment-button

ref. image: I want to only(1) card as per active IonSegmentButton, right now showing all 3 segment content.

[image: Show card section as per active IonSegmentButton]

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle it with both onClick and useState. Basically you put onClick on each `IonSegmentButton` because it seems to not working onChange or onClick on the IonSegment component (weird).

So, for each `IonSegmentButton` you set a new state that we can define as

```
const [activeSegment, setActiveSegment] = useState("1") // Defining 1 as the default active segment
```

There is the working code of the proposed solution:

```
import { IonCard, IonCardHeader, IonContent, IonPage, IonSegment, IonSegmentButton } from '@ionic/react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import './ExploreContainer.css';

const ExploreContainer: React.FC = () => {
  const [activeSegment, setActiveSegment] = useState("1") // Defining 1 as the default active segment
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonContent fullscreen class="ion-padding">
        <div>
          <IonSegment value={activeSegment} color="primary" mode="md">    
            <IonSegmentButton value="1" onClick={(e) => setActiveSegment(e.currentTarget.value)}>
                Segment 1
            </IonSegmentButton>
            <IonSegmentButton value="2" onClick={(e) => setActiveSegment(e.currentTarget.value)}>
                Segment 2
            </IonSegmentButton>
            <IonSegmentButton value="3" onClick={(e) => setActiveSegment(e.currentTarget.value)}>
                Segment 3
            </IonSegmentButton>
          </IonSegment>

          <div>   
            {/* Segment 1 Content */}
            {activeSegment === "1" && <IonCard class="ion-no-margin ion-padding-bottom">
              <IonCardHeader>
                  1
              </IonCardHeader>
            </IonCard>}

            {/* Segment 2 Content */}
            {activeSegment === "2" && <IonCard class="ion-no-margin ion-padding-bottom">
              <IonCardHeader>
                  2
              </IonCardHeader>
            </IonCard>}

            {/* Segment 3 Content */}
            {activeSegment === "3" && <IonCard class="ion-no-margin ion-padding-bottom">
              <IonCardHeader>
                  3
              </IonCardHeader>
            </IonCard>}
          </div>

        </div>
      </IonContent>
        
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default ExploreContainer;
```

The `ngSwitchCase` directive doesn't exist for React. If you don't like the way I put the conditional rendering, you can move that logic inside a method that returns JSX. You can refer to the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to understand better conditional rendering.

Comment: Thank @Veenz, 
but the active state segmentButton is not working properly, on 2nd click ```class="segment-button-checked"``` is added, how can we achieve it only on one click?

Comment: Didn't notice it, sorry! I just updated the code adding value={activeSegment} to IonSegment component!